# How to use some code line only in the mac version of Electron app?

Tags: electron

I have some javascript lines in my electron app that doesn't work with Window. They only work on Mac.
When I make builds with electron-packager, the Window/PC version doesn't start because those lines throw an error.

See my code. I think that those line only work for mac version :

```
const { systemPreferences } = require('electron');
systemPreferences.setUserDefault('NSDisabledDictationMenuItem', 'boolean', true);
systemPreferences.setUserDefault('NSDisabledCharacterPaletteMenuItem', 'boolean', false);
```

How could I say to Electron that these lines should only be used in mac version? Not Windows version

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the variable provided by NodeJS: `process.platform`. If it equals to `darwin` then Electron is running on Mac.

Example:

```
if (process.platform == 'darwin') {
    // your Mac code
}
```

Check [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_platform).